# How to identify pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is my table. It does consist of A,B and C columns. Only one column value will be true at one time.

[image: Sample Table data]

My task is to identify pattern based on latest five rows.
For example
[image: latest five rows]

I need to search entire table to find whenever these five values were repeated.

If they were repeated, what was the next value avilable for these pattern and show how many times does A, B and C values were found after the pattern.

How this can be done in SQL? I am using oracle 11g. Thanks.

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: It's oracle 11g. Thanks.

Comment: _If they were repeated, what was the next value avilable for these pattern_ - what is a "next value"? Do you mean the row afterwards, or a specific value? _...how many times does A, B and C values were found after the pattern_ - how can we find something after the pattern if it is the LAST 5 rows?

Comment: Then match_recognize can help you out.

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica I mean row afterwards.. if patter is found in 8,9,10,11,12 then I need value of 13 row.  how can we find something after the pattern if it is the LAST 5 rows- pattern need to search based on 5 last rows in the entire table..

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Many thanks. I will read and try it soon.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` would work if the OP was using Oracle 12 or later but it was not available in Oracle 11.

Comment: You are absolutely right @MT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `a, b, c` value to a trinary number and then calculate a value for that row and the previous 4 as if the trinary values for the rows comprised a 5-digit trinary number and then use analytic functions to find the next occurrence and to count the occurrences:

```sql
SELECT id,
       a,
       b,
       c,
       CASE
       WHEN grp_value IS NULL
       THEN NULL
       ELSE MIN(id) OVER (
              PARTITION BY grp_value
              ORDER     BY id
              ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) + 1
       END  AS row_after_next_match,
       CASE
       WHEN grp_value IS NULL
       THEN 0
       ELSE COUNT(id) OVER ( PARTITION BY grp_value )
       END  AS num_matches
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         a,
         b,
         c,
         value,
         81 * LAG(value,4) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) +
         27 * LAG(value,3) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) +
          9 * LAG(value,2) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) +
          3 * LAG(value,1) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) +
          1 * value AS grp_value
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           a,
           b,
           c,
           DECODE(1,a,0,b,1,c,2) AS value
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
ORDER BY id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  a,
  b,
  c,
  CHECK (a IN (0,1)),
  CHECK (b IN (0,1)),
  CHECK (c IN (0,1)),
  CHECK (a+b+c = 1)
) AS
SELECT  1, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | ID | A | B | C | ROW_AFTER_NEXT_MATCH | NUM_MATCHES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
> | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
> | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  | 0 |
> | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 0 |
> | 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 12 | 2 |
> | 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 2 |
> | 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 11 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  | 2 |
> | 12 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 2 |
> | 13 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 14 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 15 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 1 |
> | 16 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 18 | 5 |
> | 17 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 19 | 5 |
> | 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 5 |
> | 19 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 21 | 5 |
> | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44beecbacf09a9acff4006501961dcdd)*